# Window Service .Net 6.0 looking for appsettings.json in c:\windows\system32

Tags: service, configuration, .net-6.0, appsettings

I've already read some post about appsettings.json in system32 folder, but i can't resolve my problem.
I've build a window service. If i lunch the exe it works, when i lunch as a service, it does anything.
If i put in c:\windows\system32 the appsettings.json it works.

this is my program.cs

> IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
> .UseWindowsService()
> .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
> {
> configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
> .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
> })  .ConfigureServices(services =>  {
>
> ```
>  services.AddHostedService<Worker>();  })
> .Build();
> ```
>
> await host.RunAsync();

and this my worker

> public class Worker : BackgroundService
> {
>
> ```
>     public Worker()
>     {
>
>     }
>
>     protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
>     {
>
>         Logging.LogInfo("Prova", "Prova");
>         ElaborazioneDatiMacchinaMain ElMain = new BASE_DEX.Threads.ElaborazioneDatiMacchinaMain();     
>         var t1 = Task.Run(() => {
>             ElMain.Start ();
>         });
>
>         OmronMain OfMain = new BASE_DEX.Threads.OmronMain();
>         var t2 = Task.Run(() => {
>              OfMain.Start();
>         });
>        
>        
>
>     }
> ```

i've try with other setbasepath but no solutions

Any idea?

Comment: When deployed worker project as win svc, I had similar issue. Instead of `configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)` I used `configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)` and it seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Neither is working for me.